# Output line to file with same name as nth column

Tags: awk

Suppose I have this.

```
24  Monkey  86  Cat
5743    Fish    6   Dog
abc Monkey  76  Dog
56  Dog 44  Fish
vfg Dog f45 Cat
```

Using the second column, Id like to output lines to a file of the same name, creating it if needed.

Monkey

```
24  Monkey  86  Cat
abc Monkey  76  Dog
```

Fish

```
5743    Fish    6   Dog
```

Dog

```
56  Dog 44  Fish
vfg Dog f45 Cat
```

I would like to handle infinite possible names rather than manually specifying them like this

```
awk '{ if ( $2=="dog" ) { print $0; } }'
```

Not sure how to use $2 as the output file name. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
{
  close(out_file)
  out_file=$2
  print >> (out_file)
}
' Input_file
```

Comment: The `close` is good hygiene, but will slow you down unnecessarily if you only have a handful of output files. The precise limit for how many file handles you can keep open concurrently is system-dependent, but I believe a typical value would be on the order of a dozen.

Comment: assuming you don't reuse the workspace, in which case you keep appending to files named after a given animal. Remember in Linux file names are case-sensitive, so dog and Dog will be in two different outputs.

Comment: @tripleee, thank you sir for your feedback I actually thought to use if condition to check if previous second field is not same as current one then close file but then it would have been check on each line so choose to close it each time here

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you intend.

```
#!/bin/bash

for animal in $( awk '{ print $2}' animals.txt | sort | sort -u )
do
    awk -v animal="$animal" '$2 == animal{print $0}' animals.txt > "${animal}_list.txt"
done
```

Hope it helps!